# Is it true that $\sigma(X+Y) \subset \sigma(X,Y)$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables.
Is it true that 
$$\sigma(X+Y) \subset \sigma(X,Y)?$$

Intuitively I think above equation is correct, since if I know both $X$ and $Y$, I know $X+Y$. But I don't know how to argue it formally.:(

Or more generally, suppose $Z$ is a random variable. Is it true that

$\sigma(Z)\subset \sigma(X,Y)$ iff there exists some Borel function $g$ on $R^2$ such that $Z = g(X,Y)$?

---

The $\sigma$-field "generated" by any family of random variables $\{X_{\alpha}\}$ (denoted by $\sigma(\{X_\alpha\})$) is defined to be the smallest $\sigma$-field for which $X_\alpha$ is measurable, i.e., the smallest $\sigma$-field containing every set of the form $\{X_\alpha^{-1}(B): \forall\alpha \forall B \in\mathcal{B}(R)\}$.

Comment: and what is the sigam,$\sigma$ ?

Comment: @Cardinal added it up. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A random variable $Z$ is $\sigma(X, Y)$-measurable if and only if there exists a Borel function $f$ such that $Z = f(X, Y)$ (see, for example, Theorem $20.1$ of *Probability and Measure* by *Patrick Billingsley*).

Use this famous result and set $Z = X + Y$. By the "if" part, $X + Y$ is $\sigma(X, Y)$-measurable. But by definition, $\sigma(X + Y)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-field such that $X + Y$ is measurable, hence we conclude $\sigma(X + Y) \subset \sigma(X, Y)$.

Your conjecture about the general case is also true --- it's also a consequence of the theorem mentioned above.