# Is sigma algebra $\sigma(X,Y,X+Y)=\sigma(X,Y)$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, measurable-sets

The question above challenged my knowledge of probability theory.

I knew that $\sigma(X + Y) \subset \sigma(X, Y)$, discussion of which can be found for example here

[Is it true that $\sigma(X+Y) \subset \sigma(X,Y)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1560157/is-it-true-that-sigmaxy-subset-sigmax-y)

My intuition for
$$
\sigma(X,Y,X+Y)=\sigma(X,Y)
$$
is that $\sigma(X,Y)$ completely determines $(X+Y)$, thus $\sigma(X,Y,X+Y)$ can not have any additional information not contained in $\sigma(X,Y)$. Is this intuition correct?

If it is correct, than how one would formalize this?

Comment: For two random variables, can you say that $\sigma(X,Y) = \sigma(\sigma(X),\sigma(Y))$?
If so, this finishes the proof because as you said, $\sigma(X+Y) \subset \sigma(X,Y)$, and then $\sigma(X,Y) \subset \sigma(X,Y,X+Y) = \sigma(\sigma(X,Y),\sigma(X+Y)) \subset \sigma(X,Y)$

Comment: Nadav's nice argument is exactly what you need. Really this is an instance of a far more general fact - whenever you have some class of somewhat algebraic structures, and a notion of "the substructure generated by", if the substructure generated by the set $A$ is a substructure of the substructure generated by the set $B$, then the substructure generated by $A \cup B$ is equal to the substructure generated by $B$. (try to convince yourself that this is true for "groups/subgroups" and "rings/subrings" and "vector spaces/vector subspaces")

Comment: @NadavKalma thanks for your helpful comment. Could you post your comment as answer so we can close this question?

Comment: In fact this is true in any [closure space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator). (that $\mathrm{cl}(A) \subseteq \mathrm{cl}(B)$ implies $\mathrm{cl}(A \cup B) = \mathrm{cl}(B)$). Don't worry too much about this - I mention it because sometimes seeing the result more abstractly can clarify it. Your intuition is definitely how I'd think about it - $\sigma(X, Y)$ means "all the events that depend on $X$ and $Y$". So if you have some events that depend on only $X$ and $Y$ and add in every event that depends on $X$ and $Y$ you just end up with every event that depends on $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two random variables, can you say that $\sigma(X,Y) = \sigma(\sigma(X),\sigma(Y))$?

If so, this finishes the proof because as you said, $\sigma(X,Y) \subset \sigma(X,Y)$, and then
$$\sigma(X,Y) \subset \sigma(X,Y,X+Y) = \sigma(\sigma(X,Y), \sigma(X+Y)) \subset \sigma(X,Y)$$